# Highlight parent menu item using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

When i click on parent menu item, it highlights all child menu items in the dropdown menu, how do i fix that.

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $('[href$="' + url + '"]').parents("li").addClass("current_menu_item");
});
```

css:

```
#menu ul .current_menu_item a /* highlight current menu */
{
    color: Yellow;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/Services.aspx" class="top_parent" title="Our services">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Construction.aspx">Construction</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Refurbishment.aspx">Refurbishment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/Experience.aspx" title="Our experience">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Ourwork.aspx" title="Our previous work">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Contact.aspx" title="Contact us">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/About.aspx" title="About us">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When i click on a dropdown menu item, it highlights its parent menu item and all my dropdown menu items, like so(yellow is highlight, blue is hover):

[image]

How do i use javascript to remove highlight on dropdown menu items, or highlight the parent menu and selected dropdown menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the child selector `>` to only target the `a` elements that are immediate children of `.current_menu_item`

change `#menu ul .current_menu_item a` to `#menu ul .current_menu_item > a`

Comment: in 5mins, its not allowing me to do it atm

Answer (score 0):

This line `.parents("li")` is locate all parents `li`, but you need only the first one.

So change it with [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and make it as:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $('[href$="' + url + '"]').closest("li").addClass("current_menu_item");
});
```

And online test with **closest**: http://jsfiddle.net/56fqd/
with **parents** : http://jsfiddle.net/56fqd/1/